# actionEvent on click, want the same for enter key java fx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I'm new to javafx and i'm using an action property for when the login button is clicked by the mouse, I wish to use the same code for when the enter key is pressed, is there a more efficient way to do this other than copying the same code. below is the code in my login controller for javafx:

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Login button selected");

        /*
         * All Exceptions caught at the GUI not at the other two layers.
         */
        try {
            /*
             * Reference 'bal' to Object BusinessAccessLogin sends parameters to Business Layer
             * calling method login() which passes the TextBox parameters usernameBox and
             * passwordBox down the layers.
             */
            if (bal.login(usernameBox, passwordBox) && (count > 0)) {

                /*
                 * Switch statement so that: user cat 1 -> Reception screen;
                 * user cat 2 'Nurses' -> triage screen ; & user cat 3 'Doctors -> treatment room 
                 */
                switch(bal.staffAccess(usernameBox, passwordBox)){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Staff Category ONE");
                    homePageParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLReceptionistPage.fxml"));
                    homePageScene = new Scene(homePageParent);
                    appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Staff Category TWO");
                    homePageParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLTriageNurseHomePage.fxml"));
                    homePageScene = new Scene(homePageParent);
                    appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Staff Category THREE");
                    homePageParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLDoctorAssessmentPage.fxml"));
                    homePageScene = new Scene(homePageParent);
                    appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Staff Category FOUR");
                    homePageParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/FXMLHospitalManagerPage.fxml"));
                    homePageScene = new Scene(homePageParent);
                    appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    break;
                }

                appStage.setScene(homePageScene);
                appStage.show();
                appStage.centerOnScreen();
                appStage.setMaximized(true);

            } else {
                usernameBox.clear();
                passwordBox.clear();
                --count;
                invalidLabel.setText("Sorry, invalid details");

                if (count < 1) {
                    invalidLabel.setText("You have been locked out of system");
                    appStage.close();

                }
                attemptLabel.setText("ATTEMPTS LEFT : " + count);
                System.out.println("ATTEMPTS LEFT : " + count);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the code I wish to call when the enter key is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but my guess of what you want is the method [setDefaultButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-).

> A default Button is the button that receives a keyboard VK_ENTER
>   press, if no other node in the scene consumes it.